# The utf-8 encoding does not work correctly

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

I am making a programme to visualise reports in HTML. It's nothing complicated, I read the CSV file added some style(for text and table) some text and read the DF as a table.
This is how code looks like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Średnie wyniki oceny użytkowości rozpłodowej loch dla rasy puławskiej.csv",sep=";")
html = f"""
<HTML lang="pl">
<head>
<title>some title</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
some style
</style>
<body>
some text
{df.to_html(index=False)}
some text
</body>
</html>
"""
with open('report','w',)as f:
    f.write(html)
```

The problem is when I try to `pd.read_csv`. When I try to read CSV I get this error:`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 9: invalid continuation byte`
I tried to change the encoding in `read_csv` to: `ISO 8859-2` but this give me an error in line f.write(HTML)
the error looks like this:`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8c' in position 1694: character maps to <undefined>`
My next two steps were to change the encoding in 'with open()' first I change it to 'utf-8'. And this worked but my text glitched, later I change the encoding to 'ISO 8859-2' but in this case text in the table was glitched.
Help please I am out of ideas.

Comment: UTF8 works correctly. The text file isn't UTF8. `0xf3` isn't a valid UTF8 byte. Where's the call to `read_csv` and what does the file contain? You can check what codepage is actually used using `chardet`.

Comment: Please post the relevant code. There's no call to `read_csv` in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's ensure that you're reading the CSV file using the correct encoding. You can try with 'utf-8' and 'ISO-8859-2'. It's crucial to use the correct encoding when reading the CSV file; otherwise, you'll end up with garbled text.

```
import pandas as pd

# Try reading the CSV with different encodings, e.g., 'utf-8' or 'ISO-8859-2'.
csv_encoding = 'utf-8'
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv', encoding=csv_encoding)
```

Now use the same encoding as the CSV file when writing the HTML report:

```
HTML = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<meta charset="{csv_encoding}">
<title>some title</title>
<style type="text/css">
some style
</style>
</head>
<body>
some text
{df.to_html(index=False)}
some text
</body>
</html>
"""

with open('report.html', 'w', encoding=csv_encoding) as f:
    f.write(HTML)
```

This code reads the CSV file using the specified encoding (in this case, 'utf-8') and writes the HTML report using the same encoding. By using the same encoding throughout your code, you should avoid the errors you were encountering.

If you still have issues, you can try changing the csv_encoding variable to 'ISO-8859-2' or another suitable encoding for your CSV data.

Comment: We already know this isn't a UTF8 file - that's what the error complains about. `use the same encoding as the CSV file when writing the HTML report:` that's actually wrong and will cause further encoding problems. Python strings are Unicode. All the text in the dataframe is Unicode. There's absolutely no reason to save the HTML file as anything other than UTF8. UTF8 can represent any character. The error `'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8c'` says that there's a character that can't be encoded in ISO-8859-2

Comment: Have you tried to read the file forcing the ISO-8859-2 and then save the file forcing the utf-8?

Comment: @DavidRojo Yes, I tried it. This solution doesn't give me an error but the text in the table is glitched. And I try already try everything from your answer. This not work.

Comment: @DavidRojo as I write in question, I can't read csv using utf-8 encoding, this gives me an error. When I use encoding='iso-8859-2' function read_csv works correctly but the text is glitched. I try to force save with encoding = 'utf-8' but this has the same result.

Comment: @DavidRojo ok, I find the solution. The file encoding was cp1252 that's why I get an error. Now when I change encoding everything work just fine. Thanks for help anyway